# INDEX (MATCH) formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`Column A` contain

`T`, `T`, `R`, `R` from `A1` to `A4`

Ex.

```
A1=T
A2=T
A3=R
A4=R
```

`Column B` contain

`P`, `O`, `I`, `U` from `B1` to `B4`

`Column C` contain

`A`, `S`, `D`, `F` from `C1` to `C4`

`D4` contain `T`

`E4` contain `O`

`F4` contain formula `=INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH(1,(D4=A1:A4)*(E4=B1:B4),0))`

As I know formula is correct but I don't know why value in `F4` is `#NA`

[image: By Formula type 1]

[image: By Formula type 2]

Comment: what are you trying to get out of it?

Comment: l have an excel ﬁle with large data. But in short
suppose column A1-A10 contain 6 (shop number) and
A11-A20 contain 7 (shop number) & B1-B20 contain
Employee name & C1-C20 contain age of employee.
D1 contain 6 & E1 contain 37 now F1, F2, F3, F4 contains formula that show employee
name whose age 37 in shop number 6.

Comment: Enter formula as an array formula i.e. by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Comment: Thanks Mirg, That was what I was forgetting. Again thanks.

Comment: You could also use `=INDEX($C$1:$C$4,SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$4=$D$4)*($B$1:$B$4=$E$4)*ROW($C$1:$C$4)))` - no array formula entry needed.  If column C was numeric then `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$4=$D$4)*($B$1:$B$4=$E$4),$C$1:$C$4)` would also work.

Comment: @  Darren Bartrup-Cook & Mirg, Thanks but that is not as what I want. Check Images in my edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised:**

*This is a revised version according to your new requirement in the comment.*

Based on your example with `Shop, Employee and Age`.  Here is what I came up for returning multiple matches.

[image]

Use this array formula (means you have to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> altogether) from `cell G2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,SMALL(IF(IF(COUNTA(E$2:E$11)=1,$H$2&$I$2,E2&F2)=$A$2:$A$11&$C$2:$C$11,ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1),IF(COUNTA(E$2:E$11)=1,ROW(G1),COUNTIFS(E$2:E2,E2,F$2:F2,F2)))),"")
```

You should be able to retrieve those multiple matches and it should also work when there is only one criteria.  I also modified the formula a little bit so you can copy this formula directly from `G2` to `J2`.  The key here is to use `SMALL` to get the corresponding row number and feed it to `INDEX` function so it can return the pertaining record.  Try and let me know if this works or not.

Comment: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqnOS.jpg" alt=" "> Thanks ian0411, your formula working but if there is only cell H6 & I6......???

Comment: I am not sure if I follow what you tried to ask here.  Here is what I got based on my understanding of your question.  I do have one result showed as you can see my formula points to `cell G3` and no result is showing.  See the pic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgvhk.jpg).  And the array formula I used in `cell G2` is `{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,SMALL(IF($E2&$F2=$A$2:$A$11&$C$2:$C$11,ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1),COUNTIFS($E$2:E2,E2,$F$2:F2,F2))),"")}`

Comment: Also make sure you point to `H2 and I2` in your `J2` formula, and remember this is an array formula.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized my mistyped. If you don't mind please check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuwYN.jpg

Comment: @iTech, check my revised answer.  I think this should work for your examples.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs0fr.jpg This is perfect answer for my problem. @ian0411, Your revised answer not working for me but Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem.  Just curious, the formula you are using doesn't work for multiple records searching though or you just don't need it?  Also, I know you made `ROW($B$3:$B$12)-ROW($B$3)+1` change to `ROW($B$3:$B$12)-1`, the reason why I did that is in case someone add a new row before the header and this formula should still work.

Answer (score -1):

Your Match String will already return an #N/A value.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have an excel file with large data. But in short suppose column A1-A10 contain 6 (shop number) and A11-A20 contain 7 (shop number) & B1-B20 contain Employee name & C1-C20 contain age of employee. D1 contain 6 & E1 contain 37 now F1 contain formula that show employee name whose age 37 in shop number 6

Comment: F2, F3, F4 also contain formula that show employee name whose age 37 in shop number 6